# Very large nested array ngFor SVG rendering performance issues, architecture question

Tags: angular, typescript, svg, architecture, frontend

I'm working on an entreprise application where I need to dynamically render SVG. SVG is used to display floor plans. SVG elements are described into a database and provided to the front-end the JSON way allowing the graphics to be rendered using templates.

I'm not using `<img>` tags because I have to dynamically change some attributes like `viewBox`, and `transform` properties.

Therefore I have an architecture related interrogation, I'm fetching very large arrays (thousands rows) from the backend, these arrays are pre-processed and parsed to get JS objects suitable in my components, the deepest level of sub-arrays is just one.

The template is super basic it consists to do a first `ngFor` loop to create `<g>`elements and then looping over nested objects describing other SVG entities (circles, paths, texts...)

In my current example, the first `ngFor` loops over 800 objects,  every subsequent `ngFor` loops between 1 to 5 objects.

The template rendering is painfully slow (it takes about 8s). The problem is that I have to reconstruct the plain SVG in the front-end. I'm using `<defs>` and `<use>` whenever it's possible but it doesn't reduce the number of loops I have to do.

Below is a portion of the template :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="...">
  <g *ngFor="let layer of layers$ | async">
    <g *ngFor="let group of groups$ | async"
       [attr.id]="group.id"
       [attr.stroke]="group!.stroke"
       [attr.stroke-width]="group!.strokeWidth"
       [attr.fill]="group!.fill">

      <ng-container *ngFor="let entity of groups.entities" ngSwitch]="entity.entityType">

        <line *ngSwitchCase="SVG_ENTITY_TYPES.line"
              [attr.x1]="entity.startPoint.x"
              [attr.x2]="entity.endPoint.x"
              [attr.y1]="entity.startPoint.y"
              [attr.y2]="entity.endPoint.y"
              [attr.stroke-width]="entity.strokeWidth" />

        <path *ngSwitchCase="SVG_ENTITY_TYPES.path"
              [attr.d]="entity.data" />

        <!-- Other entity types -->

      </ng-container>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Below is an example node from the dataset, object with `"id": 42` is a group. The groups array contains hundreds of these. This example group only has one SVG entity but in the real dataset it may contains several entities.

```
{
    "id": 42,
    "layerId": 1,
    "fill": "black",
    "stroke": null,
    "strokeWidth": null,
    "entities": [{
        "stroke": null,
        "strokeWidth": 0.1,
        "entityType": 3,
        "transform": {
            "rotationAngle": 0.0,
            "rotationCenter": null,
            "translate": null,
            "scaleX": 0.0,
            "scaleY": 0.0
        },
        "attributes": {
            "x1": "-2.425",
            "y1": "22.527",
            "x2": "-3.858",
            "y2": "22.527",
            "stroke-width": "0.1"
        },
        "startPoint": {
            "x": -2.425,
            "y": 22.527
        },
        "endPoint": {
            "x": -3.858,
            "y": 22.527
        }
    }],
    "transform": {
        "rotationAngle": 0.0,
        "rotationCenter": null,
        "translate": null,
        "scaleX": 0.0,
        "scaleY": 0.0
    },
    "attributes": {
        "fill": "black"
    },
    "entityType": 10
}
```

From an architecture point of view, even if I'm conscious Angular isn't a framework dedicated to graphic rendering in browser, do you have some architecture tricks or suggestion to overcome this challenge ?

Thanks,

Comment: I realize the data may be confidential, but could you prepare a sample dataset that we could use to test?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share any specific data regarding the _real dataset_, however, I edited my post to add an example node coming from the dataset.

Comment: You need to simplify the drawing somehow so you're creating fewer objects.

Comment: I'm using definitions whenever it's possible to draw fewer objects. Remaining objects are optimized in a way that their drawing is the simple as possible (example using one path instead of two rectangles). Some of them need to be split in two separate entities two allow user interaction in the UI (eg: rotate and translate)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try to cache it somehow - like using paging (not sure I fully understand the need, but seems reasonable you won't need to look at 800+ visual objects at the same time).

My suggestion is to lazy load where possible (load X items at a time), or load all but display X at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it's not suitable for my needs. Indeed, I have to render all objects in the array to compose the SVG because these objects describes plan features eg: walls, doors, windows, furniture...

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the trackBy directive
take a look here:
https://blog.bitsrc.io/angular-optimization-use-trackby-option-for-ngfor-directive-72c9509b2be9

Comment: I'm already using a trackBy function on `groups` however objects in `group.entities` does not have ids so I can't use trackBy on secondary ngFor loops.